# selenium.keypressnative doesn't seem to work

Tags: c#, nunit, selenium-rc

I am trying to simulate a keypress for enter key in selenium using the below statement:

```
Selenium.KeyPressNative("10");
```

It works on my colleague's PC, but, doesn't seem to be executed in my machine. It appears that selenium skips this command.

Please help.

Thanks and Regards,
Vamyip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should it be "13"

Comment: Hey, it works now. Wonder why it did not work earlier. Thanks